# Mongoid throw 16052 exception

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to use mongoid to implement the query funcation likes 'GROUP BY',but i caught an exception:

```
failed with error 16052: "exception: could not create cursor over th_test.messages for query : { sr_flag: /.*541260c5aee1a93f70000001.*/ } sort : { created_at: -1 }"
```

My code is here:

```
def messages
    map = %Q{
      function() {
        emit(this.sr_flag, { count: 1 });
      }
    }

    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {
        var result = { count: 0 };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          result.count += value.count;
        });
        return result;
      }
    }

    result = Message.where(sr_flag: /.*#{self.id}.*/).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).to_a
    result
end
```

Can someone help me explain why? I had searched a [blog](http://www.webstein.net/blog/mongodb-error-16052-exception-could-not-create-cursor-over).Does the mongoid set the created_at column as primary key?

Comment: No it's telling you that you are trying to inspect an ObjectId type field with a regular expression, which you cannot do. Use an ObjectId type for the value instead.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think so and i got the result with 'Message.where(sr_flag:/.*#{self.id}.*/)', so i think it's right.Even i use "Message.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).to_a", there is also this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had fixed my problem.The reason was someone writed a default_scope for my Message model,but [the column sorted on was not the key column of the map method](http://www.webstein.net/blog/mongodb-error-16052-exception-could-not-create-cursor-over).Just Using unscoped method to make program work.

```
result = Message.unscoped.where(sr_flag: /.*#{self.id}.*/).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).to_a
```